# Is there a command to check the size of each MySql database on the server?

Tags: mysql, unix

Is there a quick command in unix or mysql to see the size of each database on the server?

Comment: What do you mean by size? Storage size? Amount of records? Including indexes?

Comment: physical storage size, spaced used from the harddrive, including everything, indexes too, total hd space used for the database.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 
"Data Base Size in MB" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema ;
```

From [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?108,201578,201578)

Comment: This command is not working with "Your MySQL connection id is 10996 to server version: 3.23.47-max-debug" with error message...ERROR 1146: Table 'information_schema.tables' doesn't exist....any other ways?

Comment: On my machine you only / 1024 once and not twice.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I just cd'd to the mysql folder on unix and ran the command "du -h"

and it shows the size of each database on the filesystem.

Comment: It won't work if you use INNODB - all databases are stored in the files specified by `innodb_data_file_path` variable

Comment: Or if you do not have access to the server, but only to the MySQL tools.